# Asp.net MVC3 speed test on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, localhost, response

How Can I check if my web application will work fine under massive traffic on server. I mean can I check it on my localhost at the time of development? Is there any tool or plugin for that? My web application is made in Asp.net MVC3 using MS SQL Server 2008 RC2

Comment: Similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299518/asp-net-stress-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first estimate you might measure the time your actions take and log their execution times using Stopwatch and Debug.Write() statements. A cool tool to watch these times is **Glipmse**: http://getglimpse.com/

Google Page Speed as mentioned by Ramesh.

http://build-failed.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/load-testing-aspnet-mvc-part-1-apache.html

**MiniProfiler**: http://miniprofiler.com/

And certainly the link to the similar question ;-|

Answer (score 1):

You can check your local host or any website using by [Google page speed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

please refer that .

Comment: how to check localhost on Google page?