# Performance and Load testing tools

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, profiling, load-testing, performance-testing

I am looking for open source tools that can assist me identify performance issues for a web application built using Asp.net MVC and SQL Server 2008. I may need to load test the application to identify the max concurrent users it supports. Any good collection of tools that can help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299518/asp-net-stress-testing

Why is this not closed according to te same criterion as this question?

Answer (score 3):

Apache JMeter is a good tool which has a rich set of components to test different aspects of  your application.  There are components for web and database aspects of your project.

As a follow up, this tool focuses on gather metrics about the 'externals' of your application.  Things such as http roundtrips, sql duration...  You wouldn't use this tool to measure your internal .NET performance.

Answer (score 1):

The Load Testing tools that come with Visual Studio Ultimate are invaluable for load testing a .NET app.  You can get amazing insight into your app, ASP.NET and the limitations of your hardware.  I could not be more happy with it.  If you have issues setting it up, just browse the web and you will find lots of articles for troubleshooting setup issues.  That is probably the only drawback I can think of (initial setup can be a pain).

Answer (score 0):

I use jMeter for my dev load testing, it is 100% open source.

http://jmeter.apache.org/

You can set the concurrent users, login parameters etc all from the UI.

I also use the jmeter-plugins for improved reporting within jMeter.

http://jmeter-plugins.org/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=main

Answer (score -1):

I really like [dotTrace from jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).
it lays out a very nice spectrum of what part of the code is using how much of your CPU but it is not open source.

Comment: Does it support load testing?

Comment: load testing is a different thing. you use visual studio for that. dotTrace runs your code and tells you what part of your code is the most expensive so that you can refactor.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with others - JMeter is a perfect tool to load and functional testing. It has good original documentation and a lot of other sources, including [video tutorials](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/topics/14250-video-tutorials-).

Comment: user2219560 suggested that jmeter is not suited to measuring .net performance.