# Is there any way to know how many users it can handle at a time for a website developed in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, hosting

I recently developed a website in Aspnet MVC a online pdf merge tool http://onlinepdfmerge.com for merging pdf files online. I hosted it in the server. I am not sure how many users it can handle at a time. I am excepting it to handle like 4000 to 6000 daily vistors. So i wanted to know whether it can handle like 4000 to 6000 daily vistors or do i need to upgrade the hosting?

Comment: Using fiddler send concurrent requests to the critical services that you want to perform performance testing

Comment: is it possible via fiddler to send like 100 to 200 requests at a time?

Comment: shift +R then put the no of requests

Answer (score 2):

The capacity depends on many factors :

- server's hardware specification
- Input size
- Output size
- data proceing and calculations in between
- bandwidth
- type of request and protocol of communication.
- garbage of objects / memory management
- the way you wrote program and created project architecture.

Answer (score 1):

It dependes how the users are distributed in time, how big are requests etc. You would need to perform load & performance testing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing, [ASP.NET Stress Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299518/asp-net-stress-testing)).

If you have shared hosting - performing such tests might be not allowed without prior agreement with provider.

I would monitor the server load, response time etc and decide on migration when I will know the demand on resources (it current hosting is not sufficient)

Comment: Thank you for the info.. You mean the current hosting is not sufficient to handle like 6000 request per day? if not can you please suggest me any windows hosting which can do that for me?

Comment: No, I mean that you would have to measure that by monitoring tool. E.g. the average response time, timeouts sent to the user etc will give you the answer.